# Not sure of what is wrong, trying to produce a 5x5 grid python 1-25

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone can see exactly, please inform me.

**Tried:**

```
grid = [[n in range(1,6)*5]]
```

**and**

```
grid [[]*5 for n in range(1,25)]
```

**My code:**

```
grid = [[x for x in range(1,25)] for y in range(5)]
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

**Desired:**

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]]
```

Comment: This is easy in `numpy`: `numpy.arange(1, 26).reshape(5,5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating in a range from 1 to 24(inclusive) in your inner loop, which is why your lists are too long, and have the same values in them.

You somehow need to make the variable of your outer loop  dictate the inner loop so each range within the inner loop start from a different point. Also, calibrating the length of the inner range is essential.

That being said, I suggest the following to get your desired output.

```
grid = [list(range(i, i+5)) for i in range(1, 26, 5)]
```

Comment: Can this be made more compact?

Comment: How about now? I eliminated the initial multiplications I used and removed the second(i.e. inner) for loop.

Comment: Well I guess this is the most efficient single line code so far.

Answer (score 6):

It's fairly obvious that values in inner lists have to be related both to internal counter in each list (x) and *position* of list in outer list (y). Your code fails to take care about second requirement.

```
grid = [[1+x+5*y for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cut a list into sublist of 5, see this code

```
data=range(1,26)
len_sublist = 5
print [data[x:x+len_sublist] for x in xrange(0, len(data), len_sublist)]
```